# Continuity And Derivative Of A Function

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Let $
> f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> \sin^2x \sin(\frac{1}{x}), x\neq 0\\
> 0, x=0\\
> \end{cases}
> $
>
> a. Find all the points where $f(x)$ is continuous
>
> b. Find $f'(x)$ for all the points $f(x)$ is continuous
>
> c. Is $f'(x)$ continuous where it is defined? if not where and which discontinuity type is it?

So for a we look at $\sin^2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ at $x\neq 0$ this is a product of two continuous functions and therefore continuous for $x=0$ we look at $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin^2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})\leq \lim_{x\to 0}|\sin^2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})|=\lim_{x\to 0}\sin^2x |\sin(\frac{1}{x})|\leq 0\cdot 1=0$   so $$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\sin^2x \sin(\frac{1}{x}), x\neq 0\\
0, x=0\\
\end{cases}
$$  is continuous for all $x$

b. For $x\neq 0$ we can take $$[\sin^2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})]'=2\sin x \cos x \sin \frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})\sin^2x}{x^2}$$ (not sure why can we do it)

At $x=0$ we look at $$lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x+\Delta h) \sin(\frac{1}{x+\Delta h})-\sin^2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\Delta h}\mid_{x=0}=lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(\Delta h) \sin(\frac{1}{\Delta h})-0}{\Delta h}=lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\frac{\sin(\Delta h)}{\Delta h} \cdot sin(\Delta h)\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{\Delta h})\leq lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\mid\frac{\sin(\Delta h)}{\Delta h} \cdot sin(\Delta h)\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{\Delta h})\mid=lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\mid\frac{\sin(\Delta h)}{\Delta h}\mid \cdot \mid \sin(\Delta h)\mid \cdot \mid\sin(\frac{1}{\Delta h})\mid=1\cdot 0 \cdot 1=0$$

(When can I take the limit of a product of functions? just when I am sure the the limit of each function is finite?)

c. Now we have to check that $\lim_{x\to 0}2\sin x \cos x \sin \frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})\sin^2x}{x^2}$

(how do I find if this limit exist?)

In general are a and b are valid?

Answer (score 1):

First, the product of continuously differentiable maps is continuously diufferentiable. As $x \mapsto \sin^2 x$ and $x \mapsto \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ are both continuously differentiable for $x \neq 0$, $f$ is continuously differentiable for all $x \neq 0$.

Also, for all $x \in \mathbb R$, you have $0 \le \vert x \vert \le \vert \sin x \vert$ and therefore
$$0 \le \vert f(x) \vert = \left\vert \sin^2x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right\vert \le x^2 \left\vert \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right\vert \le x^2$$
for $x \neq 0$. Consequently

$$\left\vert\frac{f(x)}{x} \right\vert \le \left\vert x \right\vert$$
which enables to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with $f^\prime(0)=0$.

For $x \neq 0$, you computed

$$f^\prime(x) = 2\sin x \cos x \sin \frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})\sin^2x}{x^2}$$

**This answers questions a. and b. Remains questions c.** and specifically continuity of $f^\prime$ at $0$.
Based on similar proofs than above you get:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} 2\sin x \cos x \sin \frac{1}{x} =0$$ and you know that
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 =1$$

You will conclude that $f^\prime$ is discontinuous at $0$ with **an essential discontinuity** at $0$ because $x \mapsto \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ has itself an essential discontinuity at $0$.

Comment: My proofs for a and b are valid? why $x\to cos(\frac{1}{x})$ is essential discontinuity and not jump? as it is has a alternating limit $1$ or $-1$

Comment: @gbox You proofs for a. and b. are not correct. The key point you're missing is that $x \mapsto \cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ and $x \mapsto \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ have essential discountinuities at $0$. To understand that, compute the values of those functions for $x_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi n}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi n + \pi/2}$. What are the limits of those sequences as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Here you check whether this limit exists: $\lim_{x\to 0}2\sin x \cos x \sin \frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})\sin^2x}{x^2}$. The first term approaches zero, so we care about second (forget $-$ sign for some minuts):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})\sin^2x}{x^2} \equiv \lim_{x\to 0}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$$

which surely does not exist.

Comment: we can look only on $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ as both $\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$ and $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ are continuous? and  $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}=1$?